# Select Multiple Items from lookup in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: many-to-many, dynamics-crm-2011, lookup, account

Is there any mean to add some script or pre validation plugin that will make a lookup to be the multi select. I don't want partylist as I am not working on activities also I don't want N:N relation solution as my client has some concerns on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to create a lookup field with multi-select.

This because lookups point only to a single entity, also if you hack the control with JavaSript in order to allow the multi-select, CRM DB has not the field to store the selected values.

Comment: that is fine and I was thinking so. I've another quick question, can I allow users to view related contacts of an accounts without sharing with them

Comment: they can see if they have the security roles to see that records or if someone with the rights shared to them, no other ways to view records